# Pip doesn't show my installed packages

Tags: python, pip, homebrew

**pip won't show my installed packages.**

I did

```
brew install python
sudo -E pip install virtualenv
pip list

pip (1.5.6)
setuptools (5.4.2)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Why isn't pip showing `virtualenv`?

This pip is the version installed by brew.

When I installed python, it says:

`They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Looking in this directory, virtualenv is not there.

Doing an updatedb; locate virtualenv, I find it installed here:

`/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

**What gives? Pip installs to above location, but isn't aware of it when I do `pip list`!**

EDIT: In response to @jordanm's comment,

```
sudo -E pip install virtualenv

Password:
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-1.11.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB): 1.6MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: virtualenv
Successfully installed virtualenv
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: thank you @jordanm for the edit. i was too lazy. had a bad day with pip.

Comment: Where is the output from `pip install virtualenv`?

Comment: Added EDIT. No useful info I think. I'm certain it got installed to where I originally mentioned, vis-a-vis timestamp.

Comment: One possibility (maybe not your case) is that you run "pip list" in an active virtual env. Then it shows packages in that virtual env, while virtualenv itself was installed as system-wide

Comment: why do you use sudo to install virtualenv?
With homebrew installed python you should use your user to install it without sudo. it seems that the defautl python installation is used to install virtualenv.

You can also install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with homebrew

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -E pip install virtualenv` most likely installs virtualenv to OSX provided system-wide Python installation, not Homebrew installed Python.

Try:

```
  brew install pyenv-virtualenv
```

instead.